# PHP query code disables other query

Tags: php, html, forms, mysqli

I have two queries, one to populate my table, and the other to control the delete button for each row.  When I have the delete button query in the code, it disables the table and makes it blank.  Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Here's the code:

```
// Queries

$delquery = "DELETE FROM mods WHERE id = '$id'";
$delete = $conn->query($delquery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

// Run queries and actions

if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
   echo $delete;
}

// Table population

$query = "SELECT * FROM mods";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: What is your expected result? Do you have more than one value of `id` in the table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you empty the table regardless the condition.

Put first two lines of code inside *if* statement.

Answer (score 2):

Your `if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {` condition should encompass the whole delete query logic—especially the MySQL query—and not just the `echo` statement. Or else you will always delete the table no matter what when that code is loaded. Try this instead:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  // Queries
  $delquery = "DELETE FROM mods WHERE id = '$id'";
  $delete = $conn->query($delquery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

  // Run queries and actions
  echo $delete;
}

// Table population
$query = "SELECT * FROM mods";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

I’d also recommend reworking that `if` logic so it doesn’t throw index not set errors at runtime when `$_POST['delete']` is not set by using an `array_key_exists` in addition to the `isset`:

```
if (array_key_exists('delete', $_POST) && isset($_POST['delete'])) {
  // Queries
  $delquery = "DELETE FROM mods WHERE id = '$id'";
  $delete = $conn->query($delquery) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

  // Run queries and actions
  echo $delete;
}

// Table population
$query = "SELECT * FROM mods";
$result = $conn->query($query) or die(mysqli_error($conn));
```

Comment: Works great, and thanks for the recommendation, I'll use that instead.  Makes a bit more sense.